# How to simultaneously horizontally and vertically scroll a multi-line string in Python across the output screen?

Tags: python, ascii-art

I'm trying to create a bouncing ball effect by scrolling an ascii sphere to the right and 'below', by trying to use indents to push it to the right, and \n to push it down

```
import time
import sys
import os
x =  [''' 
            ,dP9CGG88@b,
          ,IP""YICCG888@@b,
         dIi   ,IICGG8888@b
        dCIIiciIICCGG8888@@b
        GCCIIIICCCGGG8888@@@
        GGCCCCCCCGGG88888@@@
        GGGGCCCGGGG88888@@@@...
        Y8GGGGGG8888888@@@@P
         Y88888888888@@@@@P
         `Y8888888@@@@@@@P'
            `@@@@@@@@@P'
                """"
                    ''' ]

for i in range(10):
    print('\x08'*26,'\n'*i*4, '\t'*i*23,x[0],'\x08'*26,'\r', end='\x1b[1K\r',flush= True)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

As one can see in the above code block , I searched the internet after getting desperate, to figure out how to 'clear' the screen. '\r','\b' didnt do what I intended them to; clear the screen after one ball has been printed. So I tried including every escape character and what not I could find on the internet for this purpose. None really worked, except for the 'cls' command

It's a placeholder for now since it produces a flashing strobe-like effect, but clears the screen well enough.

However the main issue is that I cant 1) horizontally scroll using `''*i` or `'\t' * i` technique I saw on Automate The Boring Stuff by Al Swigart for 'indenting' text and 2) `\n * i` also does nothing to induce a vertical scrolling effect

Is there a reason why my implementation doesn't work, and how I could fix this and get a proper 'animation' of the ball falling to the bottom right?

Comment: If you want to clear the screen just follow this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-clear-screen-in-python#:~:text=In%20Python%20sometimes%20we%20have%20link%20the%20output,and%20how%20we%20want%20to%20format%20the%20output.

Comment: @Dock Thank you for your help with the screen clear issue. Is there a similar way or method to scroll the string objects as scrolling is the main issue?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that. Maybe only use a few lines over time

Comment: @Dock what do you mean by using only few lines at a time? Few lines of what exactly?

Comment: Maybe split the ball string by the newlines and display different elements over time. I don't have experience with ascii art, so I can't really help you with anything apart from suggesting this.